# Issue with using range.formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range, formula

I have a problem in that when I the following code it does not show in the cell

> wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("g2").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT('P C'!C2:j2;>[t1.xls]input!g14:n14)*E2"

If I place the formula directly into the cell the formula works perfectly.  When I place it into the cell I just get a blank cell and no result

Comment: I get the error when I enter the formula manually as well. Can you upload a sample file that we can test? If yes, then you may upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: Sorry, noted an error in the formula above it should be  wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("g2").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT('P C'!C2:j2;[t1.xls]input!g14:n14)*E2"

Comment: Nope still not working. It works when I replace `;` with `,` Are you using a Dutch Version?

Comment: Many thanks, your solution helped. I still don't know why the formula worked when typed in but not in code, but with the coma replacing the semicolon it now works in code as well

Comment: Gr8 it is working :) What are your regional settings of Windows? You can check that by clicking on `Start | Control Panel | Regional Settings`

Comment: Set to South Africa, guess I'll be switching to formulalocal or sticking to USstandards

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a version of Excel other than American English, you may want to get and set the `FormulaLocal` property of the `Range` object instead of the `Formula` property. `FormulaLocal` uses the language of the version of Excel you are using whereas `Formula` always uses American English.

Details of `FormulaLocal` are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) and a useful page about internationalization in Excel is [here](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/default.htm)

Comment: + 1 Very True. However I do not recommend `FormulaLocal` if the file is distributable.